# Non indexed field in sort clause

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field in my elastic search index mapping which would not be used for any searching. But I require it in sort clause of the query. Is it possible that I put "index" : "false" in the mapping definition ?

Basically in mapping :

```
"name":{
  "type": "keyword",
   "index": "false"
}
```

And in query :

```
 "sort" : [
      {"name" : {"order" : "asc"}}
   ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read about the [index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html) option from the official elasticsearch documents, which says:

> The index option controls whether field values are indexed. It accepts
>   true or false and defaults to true. Fields that are not indexed are
>   not queryable.

So, in your case, you are explicitly making it false, hence you would not be able to include in your query, hence sort queries will also not work on this field.

You can easily verify this yourself, by creating one such field in your index and see if it allows you to sort on that field.

Comment: Actually, I try it myself, and I found that sort on that field worked although queries on that field did not work. I guess query and sort are two different patterns like this doc says. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/doc-values.html) My understanding is that the `doc_values` control the sort pattern.